# bootstrap 5 sidebar with top nav and scrollable content

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

[image: Layout]

I want to make a layout in bootstrap 5 like this picture and am having a horrible time getting anything to work. I like bootstrap 5, but finding support for it is difficult so please go easy on me.

My first attempt is shown below. I think the eastiest solution is to wrap the 3 columns in a container and having a scroll bar for the middle column so it can flow, but all my attmepts at this have failed. Any ideas?

```
    <nav class="navbar nav-tabs navbar-expand-sm navbar-light bg-light">
        <div class="container-fluid">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ url_for('main.index') }}"><i class="bi bi-house-door"></i></a>
          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
          </button>
          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
            <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
              {{ nav_link('main.communities', 'Communities') }}
              {{ nav_link('main.sources', 'Sources') }}
              {{ nav_link('main.explore', _('Explore')) }}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <form class="d-flex" method="get" action="{{ url_for('main.search2') }}">
                    <div class="form-group">
                      <input type="text" id="q" name="q" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                    </div>
                </form>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              {% if current_user.is_anonymous %}
              {{ nav_link('auth.login', '<i class="bi bi-box-arrow-in-left"></i>'|safe) }}
              {% else %}
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.messages') }}">
                  <i class="bi bi-envelope"></i>
                  {% set new_messages=current_user.new_messages() %}
                  <span id="message_count" class="badge rounded-pill bg-dark"
                                                  style="visibility: {% if new_messages %}visible
                                                       {% else %}hidden{% endif %};">{{ new_messages }}
                  </span>
                </a>
              </li>
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link" href="{{ url_for('main.user', username=current_user.username) }}"><i class="bi bi-person-fill"></i></a>
              </li>
              {{ nav_link('auth.logout', '<i class="bi bi-box-arrow-right"></i>'|safe) }}
              {% endif %}
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
    {% block community_nav %}{% endblock %}

    <div class="row">
        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 280px;">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
              <span class="fs-4">Left Bar</span>
            </a>
            <hr>
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-auto">
              <li class="nav-item">
                <a href="#" class="nav-link active" aria-current="page">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#home"></use></svg>
                  Home
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#speedometer2"></use></svg>
                  Dashboard
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#table"></use></svg>
                  Orders
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#grid"></use></svg>
                  Products
                </a>
              </li>
              <li>
                <a href="#" class="nav-link text-white">
                  <svg class="bi me-2" width="16" height="16"><use xlink:href="#people-circle"></use></svg>
                  Customers
                </a>
              </li>
            </ul>
            <hr>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="d-flex align-items-center text-white text-decoration-none dropdown-toggle" id="dropdownUser1" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                <img src="https://github.com/mdo.png" alt="" class="rounded-circle me-2" width="32" height="32">
                <strong>mdo</strong>
              </a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-dark text-small shadow" aria-labelledby="dropdownUser1">
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">New project...</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Settings</a></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Profile</a></li>
                <li><hr class="dropdown-divider"></li>
                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Sign out</a></li>
              </ul>
            </div>
        </div>


        <div class="col">
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated -%}
              {% with tasks = current_user.get_tasks_in_progress() -%}
                {% if tasks %}
                  {% for task in tasks -%}
                    <div class="alert alert-success" role="alert">
                        {{ task.description }}
                        <span id="{{ task.id }}-progress">{{ task.get_progress() }}</span>%
                    </div>
                  {% endfor -%}
                {% endif -%}
            {% endwith -%}
            {% endif -%}
            {% with messages = get_flashed_messages() -%}
            {% if messages -%}
                {% for message in messages -%}
                <div class="alert alert-info" role="alert">{{ message -}}</div>
                {% endfor -%}
            {% endif -%}
            {% endwith -%}
            <div class="position-fixed bottom-0 start-50 translate-middle-x" style="z-index: 11">
                <div id="liveToast" class="toast hide" role="alert" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
                    <div class="toast-header">
                        <strong class="me-auto">Tester</strong>
                        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="toast" aria-label="Close"></button>
                    </div>
                <div id="Top_Toast_Body" class="toast-body"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row justify-content-center">
                {% block app_content %}{% endblock -%}
            </div>
            {% if current_user.is_authenticated %}
            <div id="user_balance" style="display: none">{{ current_user.coin_balance() }}</div>
            {% endif %}
            <!-- Site Modal -->
            <div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="siteModal" role="dialog">
              <div class="modal-dialog">
                <!-- Modal content-->
                <div class="modal-content">
                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <h4 id="modal-title" class="modal-title"></h4>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"></button>
                  </div>
                  <div id="modal-body" class="modal-body"></div>
                  <div id="modal-footer" class="modal-footer"></div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="d-flex flex-column flex-shrink-0 p-3 text-white bg-dark" style="width: 280px;">
            <a href="/" class="d-flex align-items-center mb-3 mb-md-0 me-md-auto text-white text-decoration-none">
              <svg class="bi me-2" width="40" height="32"><use xlink:href="#bootstrap"></use></svg>
              <span class="fs-4">Right Bar</span>
            </a>
            <hr>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few ways to solve this. One way is to set height:100% using `h-100`, `overflow:hidden` on the body, and `overflow:auto` on the center...

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-light bg-light">
</nav>
<div class="container-fluid h-100">
    <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-3 bg-dark text-white"> Left </div>
        <div class="col overflow-auto h-100 py-5"> 
            ...
        </div>
        <div class="col-3 bg-dark text-white"> Right </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Demo](https://codeply.com/p/FEhac9nQmi)

Comment: I tried this method and for some reason it binds all the columns together and they scroll together. When I copy the code form your demo it does the same thing, but works in the preview. I deleted my CSS styles just in case and it did not fix it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I don't know why my code does not execute properly. I can copy the code in your script and it breaks when I run it. I can copy my broken code to your demo and it works as you intended. I'm guessing my bootstrap is configed wrong.

Comment: I did not have a proper body tag. Thanks for the help.